# collections in java

Tags: java

So I have this code.  Basically it should be able to take a stock of any type, and you should be able to buy from this stock into a collection of any type, including Objects.

For the main function i have this.  Basically i have an stock inventory of strings, and I want to buy form this stock inventory of strings into a set of objects.  However, I get this error.

add(capture#880 of ?) in java.util.Collection cannot be applied to (T)

```
import java.util.*;

public class lab6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Shop<String> turkey= new Shop<String>();
     turkey.sell("pork");
     turkey.sell("chicken");
     turkey.print();
     Set<Object> possessions= new HashSet<Object>();
     turkey.buy(2,possessions);
        for(String e:possessions)
      System.out.println(e);

    }
}
```

Then this is the class file.

```
 import java.util.*;

    public class Shop<T> {

    List<T> stock;

    public Shop() { stock = new LinkedList<T>(); }
     public T buy() {
        return stock.remove(0);
    }

    void sell(T item) {
        stock.add(item);
    }

    void buy(int n, Collection<?> items) {

         for (T e : stock.subList(0, n)) {
            items.add(e);
        }
      for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) stock.remove(0);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `buy` method with this:

```
void buy(int n, Collection<T> items) {

    for (T e : stock.subList(0, n)) {
        items.add(e);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) stock.remove(0);

}
```

You were using `Collection<?>`

EDIT:

Also change your main to this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final Shop<String> turkey = new Shop<String>();
    turkey.sell("pork");
    turkey.sell("chicken");
    turkey.print();
    final Set<String> possessions = new HashSet<String>();
    turkey.buy(2, possessions);
    for (final String e : possessions) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

and write a `print()` method in Shop.

Comment: Are you sure that's what he wants? He's passing a Set<Object> to buy, and T is a String in this case.

Comment: I was right, that is what he wants.  He can't add a T to a Collection<?>.  Thats what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: cannot find symbol method buy(int,java.util.Set<java.lang.Object>) for this line...turkey.buy(2,possessions);

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Collection<?>` can contain any type of object, and `T` may not be a subtype of the `?` type. For example, you could pass in a `Collection<Integer>` and if `T` is `String`, clearly you can't do `items.add(e)`.

You need to make sure that the `Collection` holds a supertype of `T` so that it is always valid to add a `T`, so try something like:

```
void buy(int n, Collection<? super T> items)
```

Comment: Oh dang, should've thought of that! thanks...does anyone know how to iterate through a collection of items then?  (for ? e: items) doesn't work

Comment: @Jake: Since `? super T` can be any supertype, you cannot assume any specific type and so the best you can do is `for (Object e : items)`